# Render layers different from viewport

Tags: render-layers

I just made a simple scene to test render layers, but they're different from the Cycles viewport (black actually).

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/WLaKYGzj

Comment: Please use the tool dedicated to this site to upload files, thanks. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is because some objects are not set to be rendered:

In layer.001:

[image]

In layer.002:

[image]

Comment: That's what I intended to do, and it looks right in the viewport. What I don't understand is why the layer is black in the final render.

Comment: ok... did not get what you wanted... will delete that in a moment. So the question is "why it is not the same in the viewport?" ?

Comment: Yes, I thought I set up everything right relative to layers, but instead of showing one object in each layer, two layers are black in the render.

Comment: Thanks, no idea why they were set to not rendered.